# Add new data from restful api to angularjs scope

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm trying to create a list with endless scroll in angularjs. For this I need to fetch new data from an api and then append it to the existing results of a scope in angularjs. I have tried several methods, but none of them worked so far.
Currently this is my controller:

```
userControllers.controller('userListCtrl', ['$scope', 'User',
    function($scope, User) {
        $scope.users = User.query();
        $scope.$watch('users');
        $scope.orderProp = 'name';
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
            if (document.body.offsetHeight < window.scrollY +
                    document.documentElement.clientHeight + 300) {
                var promise = user.query();
                $scope.users = $scope.users.concat(promise);
            }
        }, false);
    }
]);
```

And this is my service:

```
userServices.factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

How do I append new results to the scope instead of replacing the old ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick:

```
$scope.fetch = function() {
    // Use User.query().$promise.then(...) to parse the results
    User.query().$promise.then(function(result) {
        for(var i in result) {
            // There is more data in the result than just the users, so check types.
            if(result[i] instanceof User) {
                // Never concat and set the results, just append them.
                $scope.users.push(result[i]);
            }
        }
    });
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    if (document.body.offsetHeight < window.scrollY +
            document.documentElement.clientHeight + 300) {
        $scope.fetch();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use $scope.apply() 
When the promise returns, because it isnt
Part of the angular execution loop.
Try something like:
    User.query().then(function(){
    $scope.apply(function(result){
   // concat new users
    });
    });